# How can I round a y-axis label to 2 decimal places and have a percentage symbol concatenated at the end?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frequency-analysis

I am creating a letter frequency analysis web tool. Given a sentence it should count the amount of each letter in the sentence and then display the percentage of how many times the letter is in the sentence. For example "hello" h is 20.00% e is 20.00% l is 40.00% and o is 20.00%.

But I am having a problem with formatting the y-axis labels. I want the labels to be rounded to 2 decimal spaces and have a percentage symbol at the end. Here is a list of some of the things I already tried for the yAxis.call:

- yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f%")())); // Gives percentage in thousands
- yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f") + "%")); // Makes axis disappear
- yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d => d + "%")); // Gives percentage, but not decimal spaces

I am 90% sure that the problem is with the .tickFormat and d3.format.

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const sentenceInput = document.querySelector("#sentence");
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
let letterCounts = {};
let totalCount = 0;

const margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50};
const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

const svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

    function countLetters(sentence) {
      totalCount = 0;
      sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
      for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        let letter = sentence[i];
        if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
          if (letterCounts[letter]) {
            letterCounts[letter]++;
          } else {
            letterCounts[letter] = 1;
          }
          totalCount++;
        }
      }
    }

let xAxis = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
let yAxis = svg.append("g");

function displayChart() {
  svg.selectAll("rect").remove();
  var data = alphabet.map(letter => ({letter, frequency: (letterCounts[letter] / totalCount) * 100}));

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, 100]);

  var barGroup = svg.append("g");
  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  barGroup.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

  xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f")));
}

form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  totalCount = 0;
  event.preventDefault();
  let sentence = sentenceInput.value;
  letterCounts = {}
  countLetters(sentence);
  displayChart();
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  margin: auto; 
  text-align:center;
}
textarea{
  margin:auto;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin: auto; 
}

#chart {
  text-align: center; 
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

rect {
  fill: #008080;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Letter Count</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Letter Count</h1>
    <div class="container">
    <form>
      <label for="sentence">Enter a sentence:</label>
      <br>
      <textarea id="sentence" name="sentence" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-btn">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is almost correct. The problem with it is that you're passing the datum to a function plus a string (which is itself a string), and that doesn't work.

Instead, pass the datum to the function, which returns a string, and then concatenate the other string (`"%"`):

```
yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d => d3.format(".2f")(d) + "%"))
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const sentenceInput = document.querySelector("#sentence");
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
let letterCounts = {};
let totalCount = 0;

const margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};
const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

const svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

function countLetters(sentence) {
  totalCount = 0;
  sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
    let letter = sentence[i];
    if (letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
      if (letterCounts[letter]) {
        letterCounts[letter]++;
      } else {
        letterCounts[letter] = 1;
      }
      totalCount++;
    }
  }
}

let xAxis = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
let yAxis = svg.append("g");

function displayChart() {
  svg.selectAll("rect").remove();
  var data = alphabet.map(letter => ({
    letter,
    frequency: (letterCounts[letter] / totalCount) * 100
  }));

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.letter;
  }));
  y.domain([0, 100]);

  var barGroup = svg.append("g");
  // append the rectangles for the bar chart
  barGroup.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.letter);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.frequency);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.frequency);
    });

  xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d => d3.format(".2f")(d) + "%"))
}

form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  totalCount = 0;
  event.preventDefault();
  let sentence = sentenceInput.value;
  letterCounts = {}
  countLetters(sentence);
  displayChart();
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  margin: auto;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  margin: auto;
}

#chart {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
}

rect {
  fill: #008080;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Letter Count</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Letter Count</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <label for="sentence">Enter a sentence:</label>
      <br>
      <textarea id="sentence" name="sentence" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-btn">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and for explaining it so well!